# Can bottom static when keyboard appear?

Tags: flutter, layout, keyboard, containers, textfield

When I set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in the Scaffold it seem not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD9q7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in `SingleChildScrollView()`

i.e.,

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: //your code
                     ),
```

More about `SingleChildScrollView()` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: I try it. but I want to layout static when keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TextField` inside a `Padding` and set the padding to `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
    child: TextField(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error in my login screen.
Then I use Listview for the widget design

```
return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 57),
      child: Center(
          child: Form(
        key: model.formKey,
        child: ListView(
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            Image(
              image: ImageHelper.logo,
              height: 241,
              width: 200,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Input(
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).email,
              controller: model.loginController,
              validator: (value) => model.loginValidator(context, value),
              autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
              focusNode: model.loginNode,
              onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
                model.passwordNode.requestFocus();
              },
              textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
            Input(
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).password,
              controller: model.passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) => model.passwordValidator(context, value),
              autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password],
              focusNode: model.passwordNode,
              onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
                model.handleLogin(context);
              },
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                NavigationService.of(context).navigateToRecover(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).passwordForgotten,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CheckBoxTimeline(
                    isSelected: model.isTermsAccepted,
                    color: model.isTermsAccepted
                        ? AppColors.primaryColor
                        : Colors.white,
                    borderColor: model.isTermsAccepted
                        ? AppColors.primaryColor
                        : AppColors.duskColor,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      model.isTermsAccepted = value;
                      model.notifyListeners();
                    }),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 8,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                    child: Text.rich(
                      TextSpan(
                          text: '${AppLocalizations.of(context).acceptFor} ',
                          style: AppStyles.textStyle(context,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              height: 1.5),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                                text: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                    .termsAndCondition,
                                style: AppStyles.italicStyle(context,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    height: 1.5),
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {
                                    UiHelper.launchUrl(
                                        context, appConfig.parameters.cguUrl);
                                  }),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            PrimaryButton(
              onPressed: () {
                model.handleLogin(context);
              },
              label: AppLocalizations.of(context).validate,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
```